# Controlling sed output when using a script with multiple substitute commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, scripting

I have this:

```
$ cat sedscr 
s/a/A/
s/c/C/
s/n/N/

$ cat file3
#: another
#: bbc
nanco
hello
another
```

When I do as below I get the output as shown:

```
$ sed -f sedscr file3
#: ANother
#: bbC
NAnCo
hello
ANother
```

I don't want `hello` in the output. How can I do that? The generic question is how do I remove those lines in the output that were not modified at all.

Comment: add `/^hello$/d` in your sedscr file?

Comment: @Kent I do not know that hello exists in the file beforehand.

Comment: @abc Then, how do you decide what it is that you want removed?  Is it only things that haven't been changed?

Comment: @John1024 Yes, only things that haven't been changed.

Answer (score 3):

#### General Approach

While a special-case solution for capitalizing letters is included below, in general, we might need all separate `s` statements.  This solution (as improved by Jonathan Leffler) shows how that can be done:

```
$ sed 's/a/A/; s/c/C/; s/n/N/; t; d' file3
#: ANother
#: bbC
NAnCo
ANother
```

Notes:

- `s/a/A/; s/c/C/; s/n/N/;`

  This does the substitutions
- `t`

  If any of the preceding substitutions resulted in a changed line, then the test command, `t`, jumps to the end of the script at which point the modified line is printed.

  For those who are curious, if we had used more than one `t` command, then each t command jumps if there had been any substitution since the last t command in the script (per cycle/line).  For more complex situations, the `t` command accepts a label as an argument and would jump to that label.
- `d`

  If the jump was not made, then the next command to be executed is `d` (delete).  This removes the line and nothing is printed.

For MacOSX:

```
sed -e 's/a/A/' -e 's/c/C/' -e 's/n/N/' -e t -e d file3
```

#### Special Case of Capitalizing Some Letters

This converts a, n, or c to upper case and prints the line only if a change was made:

```
$ sed -nr 's/([anc])/\U\1/p' file3
#: Another
#: bbC
Nanco
Another
```

`\U` is a GNU extension.

Notes:

- `-n` tells sed not to print lines unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `-r` asks for extended regex syntax so we don't need so many backslashes.  On Mac OSX, use `-E` instead.
- `s/([anc])/\U\1/p`

  This does the substitution which makes the first a, n, or c that appears into upper case.  The final `p` is the explicit command to print the changed lines.

Comment: Great answer, but my question is about controlling output when using multiple `s` commands. I am not asking a different way to accomplish what I want to accomplish. You see my point ?

Comment: @abc The non-GNU approach did use "multiple `s` commands."  To emphasize how general that approach was, I just added a new version where all `s` commands are separate.

Comment: Your general approach seems unnecessarily complex.  You could use: `sed -e 's/a/A/; s/c/C/; s/n/N/; t; d'` (unless you're using BSD `sed` as found on Mac OS X, in which case you have to separate the `t` command: `sed -e 's/a/A/; s/c/C/; s/n/N/' -e t -e d data`).  The `t` command jumps to a label (or the end of the script if no label is specified) if there's been any substitution since the last `t` command in the script (per cycle/line).  You don't have to do it one at a time as in the suggested version.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/[acn]/!d;y/acn/ACN/' file
```

If the first condition is not met delete the line otherwise use the translate command.

Or if you prefer:

```
sed -n '/[anc]/{s/a/A/;s/c/C/;s/n/N/;p}' file
```

Comment: The `y` command is interesting, but maps all characters, not just the first occurrence on the line.  The other command is fairly neat and does the job correctly.